# sanitize column values in pyspark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Given CSV file, I converted to Dataframe using something code like the following.

```
raw_df = spark.read.csv(input_data, header=True)
```

That creates dataframe looks something like this:

```
| Name |
========
|  23  |
|  hi2 |
|  me3 |
|  do  |
```

I want to convert this column to only contain numbers. The final result should be like where `hi` and `me` are removed:

```
| Name |
========
|  23  |
|   2  |
|   3  |
|  do  |
```

I want to sanitize the values and make sure it only contains number. But I'm not sure if it's possible in Spark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, It's possible. You can use [regex_replace](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/index.html#regexp_replace) from function.

Please check this:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([('12',), ('hi2',), ('me3',)]).toDF(["name"])

df.show()
+----+
|name|
+----+
|  12|
| hi2|
| me3|
+----+

final_df = df.withColumn('sanitize', f.regexp_replace('name', '[a-zA-Z]', '')) 

final_df.show()
+----+--------+
|name|sanitize|
+----+--------+
|  12|      12|
| hi2|       2|
| me3|       3|
+----+--------+

final_df.withColumn('len', f.length('sanitize')).show()
+----+--------+---+
|name|sanitize|len|
+----+--------+---+
|  12|      12|  2|
| hi2|       2|  1|
| me3|       3|  1|
+----+--------+---+
```

You can adjust regex.

Comment: This adds unnecessary space in sanitize (e.g. " 12" instead of "12") Is there a cleaner way to strip spaces?

Comment: @harumomo503:  Updated in answer. Removed `$1` which was empty String. If we just replace with `''` then it will not add anything.

Answer (score 1):

Otherway doing the same. It's just an another way but better use spark inbuilt functions if available. as shown above also.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
import re
user_func =  udf (lambda x: re.findall("\d+", x)[0])
newdf = df.withColumn('new_column',user_func(df.Name))

>>> newdf.show()
+----+----------+
|Name|new_column|
+----+----------+
|  23|        23|
| hi2|         2|
| me3|         3|
+----+----------+
```